# How to manually integrate a Swift static lib into an Objective-C or Swift project without adding it as a subproject

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, static-libraries

Here are instructions for adding a Swift static lib into an Objective-C project as a subproject http://paul-samuels.com/blog/2018/01/14/swift-static-library-in-objective-c/

Objective-C static lib into Objective-C works by adding a .a file and its associated headers. How to add a Swift .a file and it's associated headers (-Swift.h file)?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the Swift code or library as drag and drop.

[image]

Make sure the Copy items if needed, is checked like on the screenshot above.

To use the swift code on your objective-c class, `#import "<<Your-Project-Name>>-Swift.h"` in the class you want to use it. Finally, clean and build your project.

Here is Apple official [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html) for doing it.

Comment: @Pable Marrufo I believe your suggestion only relates to adding a Swift file to a project and not a Swift static lib to a project. I created a Static Lib with Swift files and attempted to add it to both a Swift app and an Objective-C app. In the Swift app, after linking the Swift Static Lib, there is a compile time error that the module is not found. In the Objective-C app, the 'App-Swift.h' file is generated (after adding a Swift file and compiling), but none of the classes from the Swift static library can be found.

Comment: Also worth noting - I believe a static lib binary is only accessible when header files are included. If it's true that a static lib binary can only be accessed when header files are present, and there are no header files in Swift, how is it possible to access object code in a Swift static lib binary? (The only way I was able to find is the way described in the link above, which is adding the Swift static lib as a subproject)